# How to get TwoColumnsMidExpanded after refresh

Tags: sapui5

I am using [FlexibleColumnLayout](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout) with two routes configured as follows:

```
"routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "async": true,
                "viewPath": "io.example.fclpoc.view",
                "controlId": "fcl",
                "transition": "slide",
                "bypassed": {}
            },
            "routes": [
             {
                "pattern": "jobprofile/{layout}",
                "name": "jobprofile",
                "target": [
                    "Second",
                    "Third"
                ]
             },
             {
                "pattern": ":layout:",
                "name": "first",
                "target": ["First"]
            }],
```

When the app is started it shows the root path, which is correct. Pressing the button `Go to jobprofile`, it routes to `/jobprofile`. Then pressing `F5` it shows only OneColumnLayout, although the path is `/jobprofile`.

[image]

The source https://github.com/softshipper/fclpoc.

How to stay on TwoColumnLayout after refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `layout` to your `jobprofile` route:

```
             {
                "pattern": "jobprofile",
                "name": "jobprofile",
                "layout": "TwoColumnsMidExpanded",
                "target": [
                    "Second",
                    "Third"
                ]
             },
```